# Ajax returns together undefined and valid data from a object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I've read a lot of post when Ajax return undefined data, but when I've tried to build a simple graphic using chart js, I've found a big problem. 
The object I build to return data, returns undefined and valid data together. 
Let me explain.

The object:

```
    public class ChartData
    {
      public string label { get; set; }
      public decimal zeroValue { get; set; }
      public decimal zeroValueRead { get; set; }
      public string spanValue { get; set; }
      public string spanValueRead { get; set; }
    }
```

The population in web service:

```
    List<ChartData> iData = new List<ChartData>();              

    List<MaintenanceCalibration> cals = new MaintenanceCalibration().GetCalibrationsByAnalyzer(Convert.ToInt32(analyzerId))
      .Where(m => m.AnalyzerMeasureId == Convert.ToInt32(analyzerMeasureId)).ToList();

    foreach (MaintenanceCalibration item in cals)
    {
      iData.Add(new ChartData
      {
        label = item.Date.ToShortDateString(),
        zeroValue = item.ZeroValue,
        zeroValueRead = item.ZeroValueRead,
        spanValue = item.SpanValue.ToString().Replace(",", "."), 
        spanValueRead = item.SpanValueRead.ToString().Replace(",", ".")
      });
    }

    return iData;
```

The ajax calling:

```
        $(function () {
          var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            analyzerId: 3,
            analyzerMeasureId: 7
          });

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Maintenance/controlchart.asmx/getLineChartData",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess_
          });

          function OnSuccess_(response) {
            var aData = response.d;
            var str = "";

            $.each(aData, function (inx, val) {
              str += val.label + ' - ' + val.zeroValues + ' : ' +
               val.zeroValuesRead + ' | ' +
               val.spanValue + ' : ' + val.spanValueRead + ' ||| ';
            });

            $('#data').text(chk);
          }

        })
```

The return data:

```
23/08/2016 - undefined : undefined | 100.0000 : 99.6000
22/09/2016 - undefined : undefined | 100.0000 : 99.3000
21/10/2016 - undefined : undefined | 100.0000 : 99.3000
21/11/2016 - undefined : undefined | 100.0000 : 99.5000 
19/12/2016 - undefined : undefined | 100.0000 : 99.6000
24/01/2017 - undefined : undefined | 100.0000 : 99.6000
```

But if I call server side the population of the object I obtain:

```
23/08/2016 - 0,1000 : 0,0000 | 99,6000 : 100,0000 
22/09/2016 - 0,1500 : 0,0000 | 99,3000 : 100,0000 
21/10/2016 - -0,1000 : 0,0000 | 99,3000 : 100,0000 
21/11/2016 - 0,1000 : 0,0000 | 99,5000 : 100,0000 
19/12/2016 - -0,0500 : 0,0000 | 99,6000 : 100,0000 
24/01/2017 - 0,0000 : 0,0000 | 99,6000 : 100,0000
```

This output is in italian language so the commas in numbers.

Someone can help me with this strange behaviour of the code?

Comment: There might be issues with `val.zeroValues ` and ` val.zeroValuesRead`.

Comment: val.zeroValues != val.zeroValue and zeroValueRead!=zeroValuesRead

Comment: I think I'm completely blind! I loose a half a day for this mistake.
Thank you @edkeveked and sumeet for the fast answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way you are populating your service from the backend, try to access in your js this way

```js
str += val.label + ' - ' + val.zeroValue + ' : ' +
               val.zeroValueRead + ' | ' +
               val.spanValue + ' : ' + val.spanValueRead + ' ||| ';
```